# inserting a Date to SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite

This two functions are for insert or update the date that input by the user to the table poeple

```
def insert_date(Id, date):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(DB)
    cursor=conn.execute('INSERT INTO poeple (date) VALUES (?)',(date))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def update_date(Id, date):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(DB)
    cursor=conn.execute('UPDATE poeple SET date=? WHERE ID ='+str(Id),
                        (date))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

But i faced this error :
cursor=conn.execute('INSERT INTO poeple (date) VALUES (?)',(date))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 9 supplied.
what does this error mean?

Comment: the date is passed to function as parameter,

Answer (score 1):

sqlite's [execute function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) `parameters` argument should be an `Iterable`.

You forgot a `,` when calling `conn.execute('INSERT INTO poeple (date) VALUES (?)',(date)`

It should be:
`conn.execute('INSERT INTO poeple (date) VALUES (?)', (date,)`

Because:

```py
a = 1
print(type((a)))
# <class 'int'>

print(type((a,)))
# <class 'tuple'>
```